React _blank page just before redirecting to actuall page
first time on stackoverflow asking question :) Did somebody had a problem when using  to redirect to new window(tab) in browser when we click on it, you very shortly see blank page just before redirect occurs? If someone could help with it i would appreciate very much.
`<Link
   to={routeName}
   target='_blank'
   rel='noopener noreferrer'
>
  redirect
</Link>`

Tried to redirect to another tab when clicking on link, but before that there is briefly blank page shown which is not the desired thing.
